# It doesn't show me scores in the UI, what can I do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote several scripts that I will now put below, to create the score and also display it in the UI. But I don't understand if I messed up the code or I didn't connect something in the scene.

This script is about colliding and adding score

```
public class CollisionFruit : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "pacman")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            ScoreManager.valorePunti += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

while this should display it in the UI

```
using TMPro;
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text punti;
    public static int valorePunti;

    void Start()
    {
        valorePunti = 0;
        punti.text = "SCORE: " + valorePunti.ToString();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        punti.text = "SCORE: " + valorePunti.ToString();
    }

}
```

I also wrote this other code which should theoretically do the same thing

```
public class Frutta : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    // Start is called before the first frame update 
    void Start() 
    { 
  
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    { 
        Destroy(gameObject); 
        Punti.punteggio += 10; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame 
    void Update() 
    { 
  
    } 
}
```

and this to display in the UI

```
public class Punti : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public static int punteggio; 
    // Start is called before the first frame update 
    void Start() 
    { 
        punteggio = 0; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame 
    void Update() 
    { 
        GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = punteggio.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried typing into the text component directly to make sure you can see the text?  The font could be too large, or color set to transparent (0 alpha).  Additionally, the wrong component might be assigned in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

It may also be that there is another UI element in front of it. Then you have to move your element that is behind it all the way up in the Hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, just make sure not to change it in `Update` so often, that's not the issue anyway. Put some `print`s there to see if each method is called. Make sure you don't have any `NullReferenceException` for not assigning `GameObjects` in Inspector. Also check if your text is changed. It should be changed if you have assigned everything correctly. If it's just not visible, check its alpha and `z` position.